# calculate row difference with reference to other column value but skip the NA

Tags: r, data.table

I wanted to perform a difference calculation referring to value in other column. It's a mouthful title but what I wanted to perform should be simple in this simplified case:

```
sample = rep(c("A", "B"), each=7)
distance = c(25, 75, 150, 200, 250, 350, 450, 25, 75, 150, 200, 250, 350, 450)
y = c(NA, NA, 2, 3, 4, NA, 3, NA, NA, 2, 3, 3, NA, NA)
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(sample, distance, y)
dt[, sample := factor(sample)]
```

Now, I want to calculate the differences among distances:

```
dt[, delta := ifelse(distance == min(distance),
                     min(distance),
                     c(0, diff(distance))
                     ),
   by = sample]
```

This is correct. However, I wanted to skip the rows if 'y' column value is NA. So, I did this change:

```
dt[!(is.na(y)), 
   delta2 := ifelse(distance == min(distance),
                   min(distance),
                   c(0, diff(distance))
                   ),
   by = sample
   ]
```

I thought that this is what I wanted, BUT...

```
dt[, list(distance, y, delta, delta2), by = sample ]
```

Resulting as:

```
    sample distance  y delta delta2
 1:      A       25 NA    25     NA
 2:      A       75 NA    50     NA
 3:      A      150  2    75    150
 4:      A      200  3    50     50
 5:      A      250  4    50     50
 6:      A      350 NA   100     NA
 7:      A      450  3   100    200
 8:      B       25 NA    25     NA
 9:      B       75 NA    50     NA
10:      B      150  2    75    150
11:      B      200  3    50     50
12:      B      250  3    50     50
13:      B      350 NA   100     NA
14:      B      450 NA   100     NA
```

If the `y` value at the `max(distance)` is an NA at the maximum distance, it also gives the `delta2` an NA. I want it to calculate it as `450-250` instead of giving an NA, i.e. calculate max(distance) to the previous non-NA. I wonder how to in/exclude that?